# Laravel 5.2 - One to Many or Many to Many Relationship?

Tags: laravel-5, entity-relationship, eloquent

I have the following 3 models:

```
 class Job extends Model {

     public function jobShortlists()
     {
        return $this->hasMany('App\JobShortlist');
     }
 }

 class Jobseeker extends Model {

     public function jobShortlists()
     {
        return $this->hasMany('App\JobShortlist');
     }
 }

 class JobShortlist extends Model {

     public function jobseeker()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Jobseeker');
     }

     public function job()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Job');
     }
 }
```

And the migrations:

```
 Schema::create('jobs', function(Blueprint $table)
 {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('job_title', 100);
        ...
 });

 Schema::create('jobseekers', function(Blueprint $table)
 {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 100);
        ...
 });

 Schema::create('job_shortlists', function(Blueprint $table)
 {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('jobseeker_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned()->unique();

        $table->unique( array('jobseeker_id', 'job_id'));

        $table->foreign('jobseeker_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('jobseekers')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('job_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('jobs')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
 });
```

A jobseeker can add multiple jobs to a shortlist. What type of relationship is this between the 3 tables - is it a one to many or many to many?

What is the correct relationships that should be defined in all three models?

Answer (score 0):

You have something like this

```
 Jobs 
    - Job ID
    - Else

 JobsJobShortListsPivot
    - Job ID
    - Shortlist ID
    - Else

 JobShortLists
    - ShortList ID
    - JobSeeker ID
    - Else

  JobSeekers
    - JobSeeker ID
    - Else
```

On JobSeekers Model:

```
 function shortlists(){
     return $this->hasMany("\App\JobShortLists");
 }
```

On JobShortLists Model:

```
 function jobs(){
     return $this->belongsToMany("\App\Jobs", "JobsJobShortLists", 
          "Shortlist ID", "Job ID");
 }
```

I've used like this and succeeded before and my first learning source was:

http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Hope it helps to you too.